# PHP Imagick equivalent of ImageMagick's Convert -thumbnail 150x100^

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

Up until now, I've been using the following command:

```php
    $shell_command = "/usr/bin/convert '".$file_name."' -thumbnail  150x100^ -set filename:f '%t' +adjoin '".$thumb_name."'";                                

    shell_exec($shell_command);
```

What would be the equivalent using the PHP Imagic library?

EDIT: The following is close but doesn't seem to be cropping the same way. I'm getting a squashed image.

```
    $im = new imagick( $file_name );

    $im->cropThumbnailImage( 150, 100 );

    $im->writeImage( $thumb_name );
```

Comment: I would say it's going to be http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.thumbnailimage.php

Answer (score 1):

The '**^**' simply is just a short-hand method for [cutting the thumbnail to fit](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#cut). I've seen some clever usages of [Imagick::setOption](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setoption.php) to implement special flags, but the easiest way would be to use the [Imagick::thumbnailImage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.thumbnailimage.php) followed by [Imagick::cropThumbnailImage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.cropthumbnailimage.php). Create a best fit image, and crop anything outside of desired bounds.

```php
$width  = 150;
$height = 100;

$img = new Imagick( $file_name );

// Best fit thumbnail
$img->thumbnailImage( $width, $height, TRUE, FALSE );

// Optional gravity
$img->setGravity( Imagick::GRAVITY_CENTER );

// Crop bleeding edge
$img->cropThumbnailImage( $width, $height );

$img->writeImage( $thumb_name );
```